# How to catch the data from local storage fastly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a data in localStorage I catch them by OnInitializedAsync method in mainLayout component and pass them to many component but it spends a lot of time how to inhance it ?
this is my code

**MainLayout.rezor**

```
<div class="page">
        <NavMenu/>
        <CascadingValue Value="this">
            <main class="margin-page container px-0">
                <article class="px-1">
                    @Body
                </article>
            </main>
        </CascadingValue>
</div>
@code
{
    public List<Product> product { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
    Navbar navbar { get; set; }
    
    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await GetProducts();

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    public async Task GetProducts()
    {
        var result = await _localStorageService.GetItem<List<Product>>("Items");
        if (result is not null)
        {
            product = result;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** the number of Items in list which I catch from local storage is more than 3000

Comment: Can you time the operation with a Stopwatch? What device are you using? Have you tried with a different web browser?

Comment: I rarely fetch data in the OnInit methods, but instead in the OnAfterRender method. This way i can let the UI update when the data is available and the feel for waiting is less. I also prefer a state management (like Redux is for React ) over cascading data all over my application. Don't know if a state management makes it faster though.

Comment: @Cedervall - Why?  If you use the normal lifecycle async methods you get a component render on the first await to get the data and you can display what "Loading" messages you want at that point.  Using `OnAfterRender` to do things that then need another render is a double loop through the (already expensive) component lifecycle.  I reserve the `OnAfterRender` for JS Interop where you need to do some client side UI stuff.  Otherwise I don't use it and actually disable it in 99% of my components.

Comment: Mr  Maciek, the time is more than 15000 sec, I am using chrome

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Ok, wrong of me to say I do most fetches in the after render method. For me it depends. If there is data the view needs to work I fetch it directly in OnInit method, but data that isn't required on the screen right away I tend to do in the onAfterRender method. This is to start the download of that data as early as possible, so when the user get to that point, the data should already be awailable. Thus generating a more smooth experience for the user. This is the smoothest way I found, but if there's a better way please let me know :)

Comment: @Cedervall - Hi. Ask a question on here with a minimal reproducible example.  Without context it's hard to judge whether there's a different way.

Comment: @HaneenAl-fakhry - 15 seconds sounds like a lot of data stored in local storage.  Why do you store it in local storage rather than retrieve it from the data store into a session service when you first need it?